# Getting data from dynamic form - multi-field row

Tags: php, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I am creating a form that has a option to add dynamically fields ( as rows with extra fields ). The generator is a table that just adds a  into a bootstrap wrapper. As you can see on the image below. Everything is working smooth, but I am quite clueless about the post POST programming, cause for now the var_dump seems to be messy and I am not quite sure what solution would be the best a) form the data in jquery while sending the data to php or b) merge the post data to a user array. Over all the desired output would be (PHP)

```
array()
['user1'] => 
      ['role'] => 'something'
      ['can_edit'] = > 0
      ['can_read'] = > 1
      ['can_execute'] = > 1
      ['is_admin'] = > 0
```

Just wondering how to achieve that, give me some hints. Besides - As you see "on" represents the is_checked so it will be 1 if its 0 its not present at all - but that's not a problem.

[image]

The post var_dump

```
["user"]=&gt;
  array(4) {
    [0]=&gt;
    string(5) "user1"
    [1]=&gt;
    string(5) "user2"
    [2]=&gt;
    string(5) "user3"
    [3]=&gt;
    string(5) "user4"
  }
  ["role"]=&gt;
  array(4) {
    [0]=&gt;
    string(9) "something"
    [1]=&gt;
    string(9) "something"
    [2]=&gt;
    string(9) "something"
    [3]=&gt;
    string(9) "something"
  }
  ["can_edit"]=&gt;
  array(4) {
    [0]=&gt;
    string(2) "on"
    [1]=&gt;
    string(2) "on"
    [2]=&gt;
    string(2) "on"
    [3]=&gt;
    string(2) "on"
  }
  ["can_read"]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    [0]=&gt;
    string(2) "on"
    [1]=&gt;
    string(2) "on"
  }
  ["can_execute"]=&gt;
  array(2) {
    [0]=&gt;
    string(2) "on"
    [1]=&gt;
    string(2) "on"
  }
  ["is_admin"]=&gt;
  array(1) {
    [0]=&gt;
    string(2) "on"
  }
```

My generator

$(".addCF").click(function(){

```
$("#customFields").append('<tr><td>'+sel[0].outerHTML+'</td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="role[]" /></td><td><input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" name="can_edit[]"></td><td><input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" name="can_read[]"></td><td><input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" name="can_execute[]"></td><td><input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" name="is_admin[]"></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>');
$('.mycheckbox').iCheck({checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue'});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're naming the inputs like name="user[]" ?

Usually I'll do it by adding a counter to the name field such as name="user_1" then name="user_2", etc and let the JS track that.

Then in the php I'll loop though like this:

```
$records = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    if (substr($key, 0, 5) != 'user_') continue;
    $row = substr($key, 5);
    $user = $_POST['user_'.$row];
    $role = $_POST['role_'.$row];
    $can_edit = 0;
    if (isset($_POST['can_edit_'.$row])) $can_edit = 1;
    // ETC

    // VALIDATION GOES HERE

    // IF NO VALIDATION ERRORS:
    $records[] = array('user' => $user, 'role' => $role, 'can_edit' = $can_edit;
}
```

javascript generator:

```
$(".addCF").click(function(){
    count = $('#customFields tr').length + 1;
    $("#customFields").append('<td>'+sel[0].outerHTML+'</td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="role'+count+'" /></td><td><input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" name="can_edit'+count+'"></td><td><input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" name="can_read'+count+'"></td><td><input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" name="can_execute'+count+'"></td><td><input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" name="is_admin'+count+'"></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>');
    $('.mycheckbox').iCheck({checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue'});
});
```

Comment: added my generator - last lines of question how would you implement a row'er counter?